Lag with compositor, screen tearing without
I'm somewhat between a rock and a hard place. As mentioned in the title, I've been experiencing a good amount of lag when using a compositor; a noticable delay on any display change. It's most noticable with games and video, but I experience it even in non-demanding applications (text editor, terminal, etc).
Turning off the compositor removes the lag, but comes with it's own host of issues. Most noticable is the screen tearing, which is again most noticable in games, but also occurs when scrolling on Firefox. Having the application as exclusive Fullscreen doesn't help either.
For reference,

I'm on Ubuntu 24.04, with the nvidia-555 driver and CUDA toolkit installed. I'm also using Xorg
I have an i9-9900k CPU, 64 GB of RAM, a thousand-watt power supply, and an RTX 4090 GPU. I am fairly certain it is not a hardware issue.
By compositor, I mean both compton and picom, as well as the force composition pipeline option in the Nvidia xorg configuration.
I'm using xmonad as the window manager for gnome-flashback, but I experience the same behavior with the default Ubuntu DE
I have a basic 1080p, 60hz monitor. I've experienced this behavior (both flavors) in applications locked to 60fps

Any ideas on how I can get rid of the screen tearing without the lag?
